# Generic array index out of bounds

Tags: java, generics

Ok , here is my problem . I'm learing to use generic classes and methods. I want to make an generic array list and method that will add/remove element by choosen index. I simply doesn't know how to do that . My example is calling an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Any help is welcome.
Thanks it advance .

class klasa3:

```
public class klasa3<E> {
    private java.util.ArrayList<E> list = new java.util.ArrayList<>();



   public klasa3(int initSize){ 

   }


   public int getSize() {
         return list.size();
   }

   public E peek() {
         return list.get(getSize() - 1);
   }

   public void push(E o,int indeks) {
       o = list.get(indeks);
       list.add(o);
   }

   public E pop(int indeks) {
         E o = list.get(indeks);
         list.remove(indeks);
        return o;
   }

   public boolean isEmpty() {
         return list.isEmpty();
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
           return "stack: " + list.toString();
   }
 }
```

main class:

```
public class klasa2 {
   public static void main(String[] args ) {


        klasa3 stak2 = new klasa3(13);
       stak2.push("cola",2);  // problem here
       stak2.pop(2);
        System.out.println(stak2.getSize()); 

   }


 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating an empty `ArrayList`, and then trying to get the third element (element at index 2) from it within your `push` method. That's not going to work.

Now, you're currently ignoring your `initSize` parameter in your constructor. You might want something like:

```
// TODO: Rename the class to follow naming conventions
public klasa3(int initSize) { 
    for (int i = 0; i < initSize; i++) {
        list.add(null);
    }
}
```

Or provide a default element:

```
// TODO: Rename the class to follow naming conventions
public klasa3(int initSize, E element) { 
    for (int i = 0; i < initSize; i++) {
        list.add(element);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ViktorLekić accept the answer if it is helped you. Because accepting answers in Stackoverflow will let people know that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

This is what is happening:

In the `main` method you first create a new `klasa3` object. Then you call `push("cola", 2)` on it.

The `push` method does: `o = list.get(indeks)`, where `indeks` is `2`. At this point the list is empty, so `2` is not a valid index, which causes an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

The index that you pass to the `get` method must be between 0 (inclusive) and the size of the list (exclusive). Since the size is `0`, the index `2` is invalid.